# What is the convention for naming C# files that contain extension methods?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, conventions

While creating a library to learn C#, I've realized that there are a lot of conventions on how to name files, variables, parameters, interfaces, etc.

Now, I am making a file that will contain extension methods, and thus was left wondering if there are any convention on how to name those files? Is there anything suggested by the community, even if non-official?

While looking at the [page about extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) and [the one about how to implement them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method), I realized that the name of the file used are not mentioned. I don't know if it's a coincidence.

Comment: This is going to be opinion-based... We usually have one file per class and the filename matches the class name. We use an `Ext` suffix for extension method classes. So the filename for the extension class would also have an `Ext` suffix.

Comment: Usually, the file is named for the static class, and the static class is named for what it extends; the two most common patterns are typified by `FooExtensions` for extension methods on type `Foo`, or sometimes `Foo` for extension methods on `IFoo` - for example of the latter: `Enumerable` and `Queryable` as the static types that extend `IEnumerable[<T>]` and `IQueryable[<T>]` (LINQ). These aren't rules or even guidelines, though

Comment: My take. Name it like the class you want to extend plus "Extensions". And put that class into the same namespace as the class you want to extend.

Comment: Microsoft seem to use [an `Extensions` suffix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions?view=net-8.0)

Comment: @MatthewWatson but inconsistently :) although the `Extensions` suffix does seem to be where things have landed, with early examples like LINQ simply being the wild west days

Comment: If the type I'm extending is `IEnumerable<MyType>` I name it `MyTypeEnumerable`. If the type in extending is `MyType` I name it `MyTypeExtensions` :p

Answer (score 2):

There is no defined convention (at least that I know of). It is not mentioned in [the code style doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names) and I don't see anything in the configurable [naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules).

Usual approach I've seen is to group extension methods by type they extend (or some logical concept) and give it suffix like `Extensions`/`Exts`/`Ext`:

```
public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static int CountBar(this Foo foo) => 1;
}
```

For example framework classes and Microsoft developed libraries (like EF Core) seems to favor use of the `Extensions` suffix:

- [`EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions?view=efcore-7.0) - Entity Framework LINQ related extension methods.
- [`EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutebuilderextensions?view=aspnetcore-7.0) - Provides extension methods for `IEndpointRouteBuilder` to add endpoints.
- [`MemoryExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions?view=net-8.0) - Provides extension methods for the memory-related and span-related types, such as `Memory<T>`, `ReadOnlyMemory<T>`, `Span<T>`, and `ReadOnlySpan<T>`.

Though there are counter-examples like [`Enumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-8.0) and [`Queryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?view=net-8.0) static classes containing LINQ extension methods.

Comment: Everytime someone links to code styles/rules i'm always hoping to find the updated "framework design guidelines" at the end. Collecting disappointments on that for over decade now :(